# how to catch an exception that is "never thrown" in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, try-catch, jsch

I have the following block of code, which uses the JSCH library found at http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

```
try {
    channel.put(f, filename);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("no file.");
}
```

I know that the put method can throw a FileNotFoundException when the file specified by f is not found locally, but eclipse tells me that the catch block is unreachable, and that exception can never be thrown.  When I change to:

```
try {
    channel.put(f, filename);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\yo\hello2 (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How does the signature of `channel.put` look like?

Comment: Maybe `put` is declared as throwing `Exception`, but throws `FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: Are you sure that the exception is thrown at that line?

Comment: What's the full qualified classname of that Exception class?

Comment: You should give the type of channel so someone could confirm if your channel instance throws Exception and not FileNotFoundException.

Comment: If put is declared to throw an Exception, it should be possible to catch any particular type of Exception.

Comment: the channel is declared to be of type  com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp

Comment: Printing `e.getMessage()` is usually not helpful. If this was a real FileNotFoundException, you would just get `C:\yo\hello2 (The system cannot find the file specified)` - i.e. the class name gets stripped away. If you would have printed simply `e` instead (or `e.toString()`) then you would know which exception class you should catch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your `FileNotFoundException` is wrapped in another thrown by the `channel` method and therefor you cannot catch it.

Try printing the class of the exception thrown by the method:

```
...
} catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e.getClass());
}
```

Comment: Strangely, the getClass() returns con.jcraft.jsch.SftpException, even though the stack track shows a java.io.FileNotFoundException.  Seems like I just need to catch the SftpException instead.  Thanks.

Comment: @ewok: The SftpException (as any Exception) has a `getCause()` method ... I suppose this will return the right Exception object.

Answer (score 2):

Check your import statements to ensure you are not importing a `FileNotFoundException` class from a package besides `java.io`.